# Connect to uncertified host via FTP over TLS/SSL

Tags: ruby, ftp, ftps

A vendor I grab a file from is changing from FTP to FTP over SSL.

I am trying to update my code from `net/ftp` to `net/ftptls`

The new host I need to connect to is not certified and my script reports back this error.

> hostname was not match with the server certificate

The vendor will not fix this.

Looking at `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/ftptls.rb`  I thought it wouldn't be too hard to monkey-patch FTPTLS to ignore the untrusted host.

I tried changing `verify_mode` to `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` and commenting out the  post_connection_check` line.

neither worked.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'
require 'net/ftp'

module Net
  class FTPTLS < FTP
    def connect(host, port=FTP_PORT)
      @hostname = host
      super
    end

    def login(user = "anonymous", passwd = nil, acct = nil)
       store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
       store.set_default_paths
       ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new('SSLv23')
       ctx.cert_store = store
       ctx.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
       ctx.key = nil
       ctx.cert = nil
       voidcmd("AUTH TLS")
       @sock = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@sock, ctx)
       @sock.connect
       @sock.post_connection_check(@hostname)
       super(user, passwd, acct)
       voidcmd("PBSZ 0")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the world's slowest answer, but I ran across your question and it helped my fix it myself, so I wanted to post for posterity.

You were very close, you just need to also comment out #post_connection_check.

What I did, rather than monkeypatching ruby itself, was bring a copy of this into /lib of my project.

```
module Net

  class FTPTLS < FTP
    def connect(host, port=FTP_PORT)
      @hostname = host
      super
    end

    def login(user = "anonymous", params = {:password => nil, :acct => nil, :ignore_cert => false})
      store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
      store.set_default_paths
      ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new('SSLv23')
      ctx.cert_store = store
      ctx.verify_mode = params[:ignore_cert] ? OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE : OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      ctx.key = nil
      ctx.cert = nil
      voidcmd("AUTH TLS")
      @sock = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@sock, ctx)
      @sock.connect
      @sock.post_connection_check(@hostname) unless params[:ignore_cert]
      super(user, params[:password], params[:acct])
      voidcmd("PBSZ 0")
    end
  end
end
```

I also cleaned up the param passing a bit. You would use this like so:

```
  require 'ftptls'  # Use my local version, not net/ftptls
  @ftp_connection = Net::FTPTLS.new()
  @ftp_connection.passive = true
  @ftp_connection.connect(host, 21)
  @ftp_connection.login('user', :password => 'pass', :ignore_cert => true)
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably too late for Poul but I found the [double-bag-ftps gem](https://github.com/bnix/double-bag-ftps) to be sufficient and easy to use when I had to do something similar.